# Java JFrame is displayed incorrectly

Tags: java, swing, jframe, transparent

When I run my program, the `JFrame` shows what is in the `JFrame` and then what is behind the `JFrame` when it is opened.

[image: frame behaving badly]

```
public class ChuckysAdventure extends JFrame { // Main Class

    public ChuckysAdventure(){
        setTitle("Chuckys Adventure");
        setSize(700, 700);
        setResizable(false);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
    public void paint (Graphics g){
        g.drawString("Hi. I'm Chucky. Wanna play?", 250, 250);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){  // Starts game
         new ChuckysAdventure();
    }
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem here? Could you outline what you want it to look like? It looks like your frame has transparency issues. If you could provide the code, we could perhaps find the issue.

Comment: Looks like you've set the opacity of the frame to something other then `1`...or you're setting the background color that has an alpha component or you've screwed with the paint chain...I can keep guessing or you could provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @MadProgrammer  code updated

Comment: Try putting all your setSize, setTitle etc. Before setting it visible.

Comment: Make sure you pack the frame using pack()

Comment: @codeNinja still the same error :/

Comment: @TastyLemons That makes the window very small. I must suck XD

Comment: Is it still transparent?

Comment: I can't reproduce the same issue with the code you've posted. But remember to call `super.paint(g)` in your `paint` method. Also you shouldn't be painting on `JFrame` instead paint on `JPanel` and override `paintComponent` and call `super.paintComponent(..)`

Answer (score 9):

Welcome to the wonderful world of "Honey, I broke the paint chain"...

Painting in Swing is made up of a series of chained method calls which work together to produce the final result, one of those methods actually fills the `Graphics` context with the components background color

Failing to honour this paint chain will cause no end of paint artifacts.  `Graphics` is a shared resource, meaning that everything that is painted within a given paint cycle will use the same instance of the `Graphics` context.  If you fail to ensure that the paint chain is completed properly, you will end up with any number of awesome paint artifacts.

Your initial fix would be to change...

```
public void paint (Graphics g){
    g.drawString("Hi. I'm Chucky. Wanna play?", 250, 250);
}
```

to...

```
public void paint (Graphics g){
    super.paint(g);
    g.drawString("Hi. I'm Chucky. Wanna play?", 250, 250);
}
```

You next fix would be to avoid overriding `paint` of top level containers like `JFrame` a part from the fact that it's not double buffered and painting will occur beneath the frames decorations, its all to easy to completely screw up the paint process

Instead, you should be using something like `JPanel` and overriding it's `paintComponent` method instead

Take a look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for more details